# Конструкции типа «избегать + глагол»

Tags: грамотная-речь, глаголы, словосочетания

> Рассматривая сходства и различия, **избегайте учитывать** одиночные примеры указанных явлений.

Верно ли выделенное словосочетание и правильно ли говорить *избегать + глагол* вообще?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[ИЗБЕГА́ТЬ](https://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/ushakov/819278)
2. избегаю, избегаешь, несовер. (к избежать и к избегнуть), **кого-чего и с инф.**
**1.** Уклоняться от чего-нибудь, сторониться кого-чего-нибудь.
*Он избегал неприятных разговоров. Избегает знакомых, предпочитая уединение. **Он избегал смотреть в глаза.***
**2.** Избавляться, спасаться от чего-нибудь, не подвергаться чему-нибудь.
*Ни один преступник не избегает наказания.*

*Он, казалось, избегал говорить о себе.*
[Коллектив авторов. Вереница литер](https://books.google.ee/books?id=KfLLAAAAQBAJ&pg=PA509&lpg=PA509&dq=%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B1%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%B0%D0%BB%20%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C&source=bl&ots=jvvoYhCFAL&sig=9eYcvn9k9a8yrmP97SQ38NC4Tjo&hl=ru&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjIrJuy0eLcAhWFZpoKHdD7B1IQ6AEwEHoECAEQAQ#v=onepage&q=%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B1%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%B0%D0%BB%20%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C&f=false)

*Табарен волновался. Он сам хотел судить о своей работе в полном ее объеме, а потому избегал смотреть ранее этого вечера готовую уже ленту на свет.*
А. Грин. Забытое

**Дополнение**
С. И. Ожегов, Н. Ю. Шведова. Толковый словарь русского языка:
[избегать](http://%D1%87%D1%82%D0%BE-%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B0%D0%B5%D1%82.%D1%80%D1%84/%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B1%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C)
**2.** кого-чего и с неопр. Сторониться, уклоняться от чего-нибудь.
Избегать знакомых. **Избегать встречаться с кем-нибудь.**

*Она избегала оставаться с ним наедине, избегала встречаться с ним взглядом.*
Catè Spini. Стереть прошлое

*Наверное, я говорил слишком громко, вознаграждая себя за то, что такие вещи мы старались в те времена не произносить вслух, даже думать об этом избегали.*
Д. Гранин. Наш комбат

Answer (score 4):

На мой слух, всё, что идёт глаголом после "избегайте", звучит коряво, но это могут быть издержки моего авторского идеолекта. Проверяем корпусом:

"избегать + существительное" = 159 единиц.

"избегать + глагол" = случаев десять.

- с восемнадцатого века и до пятидесятых годов двадцатого встречается широкая вариативность (включая непереходные глаголы):

> Избегайте ходить.
>
> Избегайте отвечать ему.
>
> Избегайте только, во избежание бесплодных толков, некоторое время
>   ставить означенного околоточного на местах особого скопления публики.
>
> Избегайте смотреть прямо.

В тридцатые-пятидесятые годы распространение получает форма дополнения в виде переходного глагола + объекта действия (хотя формы непереходных глаголов, возвратных глаголов тоже есть):

> Но избегайте ввязываться в бои, устраивать стычки, рискуя собой
>
> Избегайте слишком сильно пудрить нос
>
> ...избегайте вдыхать аммиачные пары...

С шестидесятых годов встречается преимущественно форма переходных глаголов с дополнениями (по типу "избегайте пить водку").

В дальнейшем, примерно годов с девяностых, вместо глаголов появляются отглагольные существительные ("избегать" + "ходьбы / гульбы / молотьбы").

Таким образом, если верить данным корпуса, то форма "избегайте делать" считается правильной, но несколько устарелой, восходящей ещё к дореволюционным временам.

Comment: Спасибо за интересный ответ с включением корпусных данных!

Comment: Для меня это тоже звучит просторечно, вопрос только в том, плох только стиль или грамматика тоже. Есть тест (один из возможных) для определения переходности глагола: если имеющийся при глаголе инфинитив заменяется существительным в винительном или родительном падеже, то глагол переходный. В данном случае устанавливаемая тестом _переходность_ глагола противоречит практике его употребления (винительный падеж существительного при нём считается **ошибкой** -  справочник Розенталя по управлению в русском языке).

Comment: @Manjusri Я невольно повторил сказанное Alex_ander'ом в тексте своего ответа, мне жалко его (ответ) убивать, посмотрите там.

Answer (score 2):

Ответ, я считаю, уже дан: сочетание грамматически возможно, но выглядит несколько тяжеловесно.
Я не буду повторять аргументацию, в качестве некоторого дополнения я бы хотел развернуто прокомментировать вот это:

> На мой слух, всё, что идёт глаголом после "избегайте", звучит коряво,
>   но это могут быть издержки моего авторского идеолекта.

- Мне тоже не очень нравятся подобные конструкции. Только дело, имхо, не в просторечии, а в изменении значения и управления "избегать". Инфинитив беспроблемно цепляется только к переходным глаголам, поскольку занимает место прямого дополнения. Насколько помню, раньше глагол "избегать" допускал при себе винительный падеж (наряду с родительным) - и инфинитив прекрасно становился на его места. С потерей переходности глагол "избегать" перестал естественным путем принимать и инфинитив. Отсюда и ощущение некорректности.

Но проверять всё-таки надо не по корпусу, а по словарям сочетаемости; к сожалению, нет под рукой... А если уж по корпусу - то с анализом года и автора. Иначе в выборку попадают и просторечия, и устаревшие варианты, и того и другого там хватает.

Answer (score 1):

Не вижу проблем в употреблении избегать + инфинитив. На форуме обсуждались более странные случаи подобных конструкций, и те находили подтверждение.

Приведу пару цитат:

> Но без этой внутренней, подсознательной потребности **избегайте
>   смотреть** прямо, на несуществующую стену или вдаль... (Константин
>   Станиславский)
>
> **Избегайте читать** Бальмонта — у него стих неправильный.
>   (Максим Горький)

Comment: Старенькие примеры, честно говоря. Не устарела ли конструкция?

Comment: Современных примеров очень много. Я же сознательно стараюсь искать примеры не Дашковой или Марининой.

Comment: Пушкин был молодец и писал «деревня пришла мне по сердцу», но это вовсе не значит, что сейчас так говорить правильно. Это я к тому, что мне интересна современная ситуация.

Comment: Согласен с Вами. Если бы я не встретил на эти две цитаты около сотни современных, я бы сказал, что в современном языке употребляется редко. А так, судя по статистике, наоборот. Но цитаты я буду выбирать известных людей, пусть это будет мой стиль.

Comment: так нужно это показать в ответе :) К тому же, если вы  нашли 100 вхождений в 100000000-м корпусе, то это не значит, что конструкция хорошо себя чувствует в современном языке.

Comment: Учту на будущее, спасибо. Но я смотрю не в корпусе, а в гугло-книгах. Тоже для разнообразия (раз все смотрят в корпусе). Поиск в сети моё хобби, так что я доверяю своему (поисковому) чутью. Но если бы мне самому выражение казалось некорректным, я бы поостерёгся приводить голые цитаты вопреки чутью (акцентировал бы внимание на этом несоответствии).

Comment: понял, спасибо вам за ответ — проголосовал за.

Answer (score 0):

**Рассматривая сходства и различия, избегайте учитывать одиночные примеры указанных явлений.**

В современном языке эта фраза воспринимается как **неоднозначный  совет, заключенный в архаичную форму.**

Здесь возможны два варианта:

(1) Рассматривая сходства и различия, **не учитывайте одиночные примеры** указанных явлений. (**Не надо**  учитывать одиночные примеры).

(2) Рассматривая сходства и различия, **старайтесь не учитывать одиночные примеры** указанных явлений. (Одиночные примеры **лучше не учитывать**).

Он избегал смотреть ей в глаза? Скажите просто: он старался не смотреть ей в глаза.